# SPARK Scala Error on converting RDD with Array[String] to DF via createDataFrame

Tags: apache-spark

This below works fine:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructField,StructType,IntegerType, ArrayType, LongType}

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq((1.0, 2.0), (0.0, -1.0), (3.0, 4.0), (6.0, -2.3))).toDF("x", "y")
val newSchema = StructType(df.schema.fields ++ Array(StructField("rowid", LongType, false)))

val rddWithId = df.rdd.zipWithIndex
val dfZippedWithId =  spark.createDataFrame(rddWithId.map{ case (row, index) => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq ++ Array(index))}, newSchema)
```

This structure:

```
rddWithZipId: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[((String, Int, Array[String]), Long)] = ZippedWithIndexRDD[149] at zipWithIndex at command-2467674133341972:32
```

produces an error when I do exactly the same thing as for earlier example. The only difference is the Array[String].

The error produced is:

```
notebook:45: error: value toSeq is not a member of (String, Int, Array[String])
val dfPosts =  spark.createDataFrame(rddWithZipId.map{ case (row, index) => Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq ++ Array(index))}, newSchema)
```

Looking around I cannot see why this would not work. I note that even though I see 4 types / elements in the RDD, I can observe that the Row is seen as 1 structure.

Any ideas? There are possible other ways, but I do not understand why the first example works and the second does not? Array[String] seems to be the culprit. In fact it has to be so, but how to get around this?

Just doing this:

```
val dfPosts =  rddWithZipId.toDF()
```

returns a nested schema as below, so may be that is the go, but none-the-less the question remains as per above. The nested structure means I can achieve what I want to do, that is not an issue.

```
root
  |-- _1: struct (nullable = true)
  |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
  |    |-- _2: integer (nullable = false)
  |    |-- _3: array (nullable = true)
  |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
  |-- _2: long (nullable = false)
```

I am thinking a nested structure needs to be defined somehow.

Thanks in advance.

UPD: In hindsight must have been studying late, no longer sure what question was about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There are possible other ways, but I cannot understand why the first example works and the second does not? Array[String] seems to be the culprit.

It has nothing to do with the content of the first element. It is all about types. If you take a look at the types `rddWithId` is

```
RDD[(Row, Long)]
```

while the second structure is

```
RDD[((String, Int, Array[String]), Long)]
```

So in the first case `_1` is `org.apache.spark.sql.Row` which provides `toSeq` method, while in the second case `_1` is `Tuple3[_, _, _]` which doesn't provide such method.

If you want to make it work

```
Row.fromSeq(row.toSeq ++ Array(index))
```

replace

```
Row.fromSeq(("a", 1, Array("foo")).productIterator.toSeq ++ Array(index))
```

or better (why initialize additional `Array` for each call?)

```
Row.fromSeq(("a", 1, Array("foo")).productIterator.toSeq :+ index)
```

Comment: It's a long story on the Array, but I will try what you state. I can't say I find it obvious but a little bell is going on Product. I know the second nested approach will do what I want. I will get back,.

Comment: I have difficulty following your answer (and why I got a -1). I ran the first example that works with 3 elements. No issue. I am missing something, it must have to do with the Array meaning you need to go to Product.

Comment: In my case it is the fact that the Array is added - as with a third attribute it is no issue, and that requires productIterator. I had forgotten that. Nice. Also row.productIterator. Good stuff.

Comment: Even though forgotten, it is actually a good aspect for others imho.